# Automatically making a newly saved payment method default in WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I've been trying to find an appropriate action(s) hook to do what I'm describing in my title.

Under My account > payment methods I want any newly saved payment method by the user to be set as default

I noticed the "after_woocommerce_add_payment_method" action under "add_payment_method()" function but I don't think I can simply pass a hidden input for this, especially when there is an existing default method.

"is_default" is what seems to be the identifying attribute for the default saved payment method.

I noticed that the built-in functionality for this is under class-wc-payment-tokens.php, with the function named set_users_default() so I could possibly call this provided I can hook into an action after the payment method ( Token ) has been saved ( to get the Token/method ID ) but before WC redirects to the payment-methods page.

Any ideas if I'm thinking this the right way?